# Vue.js find which component emitted an event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to have a component representing a shopping item.
I'll have one of this component for every item in my shopping list.
I don't know how to update the parent data (the shopping list) when the child is edited (the shopping item)

**Shopping List**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <shopping-item
      v-for="(item, index) in shoppingList"
      :key="index"
      :propsName="item.name"
      :propsQuantity="item.quantity"
      @shoppingItemEdited="handleEdit"
    ></shopping-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ShoppingItem from "./components/ShoppingItem.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ShoppingItem,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      shoppingList: [
        { name: "apple", quantity: 8 },
        { name: "banana", quantity: 3 },
        { name: "kiwi", quantity: 7 },
        { name: "peach", quantity: 5 },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleEdit(itemEdited) {
      // How to get the index of the shopping-item that has been updated ?
      // shoppingList[???] = itemEdited
      console.log(itemEdited);
      // => {name: "white peach", quantity: "6"}
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Shopping Item**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="name" placeholder="ex: banana" @change="updateParent" />
    <input
      v-model="quantity"
      type="number"
      placeholder="ex: 3"
      @change="updateParent"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      quantity: null,
    };
  },
  props: {
    propsName: String,
    propsQuantity: Number,
  },
  created() {
    this.name = this.propsName;
    this.quantity = this.propsQuantity;
  },
  methods: {
    updateParent() {
      this.$emit("shoppingItemEdited", {
        name: this.name,
        quantity: this.quantity,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

So I have few questions:

1. How can I know witch component emited the event 'shoppingItemEdited' ? If I knew it, I could find out which shoppingList item I should update.
2. I red I should not update props in the child, so I create data based on props, is that a standard way of doing that ?

```
this.name = this.propsName;
this.quantity = this.propsQuantity;
```

Comment: use the `key` prop in the emit ... `:key="index"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just pass an index to a handler: `@shoppingItemEdited="handleEdit(index, $event)"`
2. No it's not "standard" - `created` hook is called only once when component is created, so if value of prop changes later (from parent), `data` will not update. It's probably not a problem in your case but usually its better to use `computed`:

```js
computed: {
  name: {
    get() { return this.propsName },
    set(value) { 
      this.$emit("shoppingItemEdited", {
        name: value,
        quantity: this.quantity,
      }); 
    }
  }
}
```

...handle event in parent and the change will propagate (by props) to a child